# Most computationally efficient way to count consecutive repeating values

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a boolean array

```
a2= np.array([False, False, True, False, False, True, True, True, False, False])
```

I want an array which contains the number of elements of each group of True values

Desired result:

```
np.array([1, 3])
```

Current solution:

```
sums = []
current_sum = 0
prev = False
for boo in a2:
    if boo:
        current_sum+=1
        prev = True
    if prev and not boo:
        sums.append(current_sum)
        current_sum = 0
    if not boo:
        prev = False
np.array(sums)
```

May not be the most computationally efficient. Seems like `np.cumsum` could be used in a creative manner but I am not able to think of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way using `np.where` + `np.diff` to identify the split locations:

```
out = [ar.sum() for ar in np.split(a2, np.where(np.diff(a2.astype(int), prepend=0)==1)[0])[1:]]
```

`np.split` is slow, so we can replace it with `zip` in a list comp and walk the over an array of indices. Also, instead of `sum`, we could index the array and use `len`:

```
idx = np.where(np.diff(a2.astype(int), prepend=0)==1)[0]
out = [len(a2[i:j][a2[i:j]]) for i,j in zip(idx, idx[1:])] + [len(a2[idx[-1]:][a2[idx[-1]:]])]
```

Output:

```
[1, 3]
```

Performance comparison:

```
import perfplot
import numpy as np
import itertools
import random

def diff_where_split_sum(a2):
    return [ar.sum() for ar in np.split(a2, np.where(np.diff(a2.astype(int), prepend=0)==1)[0])[1:]]

def flatnonzero_split_if_sum(a2):
    return [l.sum() for l in np.split(a2, np.flatnonzero(~a2)) if l.sum() > 0]

def groupby_if_sum(a2):
    return [sum( 1 for _ in group ) for key, group in itertools.groupby( a2 ) if key]

def diff_where_slice_index_len(a2):
    idx = np.where(np.diff(a2.astype(int), prepend=0)==1)[0]
    return [len(a2[i:j][a2[i:j]]) for i,j in zip(idx, idx[1:])] + [len(a2[idx[-1]:][a2[idx[-1]:]])]

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.array(random.choices([True, False], k=10) * n),
    kernels=[
        lambda arr: diff_where_split_sum(arr),
        lambda arr: flatnonzero_split_if_sum(arr),
        lambda arr: groupby_if_sum(arr),
        lambda arr: diff_where_slice_len(arr)
    ],
    labels=['diff_where_split_sum', 'flatnonzero_split_if_sum', 
            'groupby_if_sum', 'diff_where_slice_index_len'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(20)],
    equality_check=np.allclose,  
    xlabel='~len(arr)'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Insteead of `len(ar[ar])` you can do `ar.sum()`

Comment: I edited my answer with the code for testing the performances. You version is the fastest proposed so far.

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 please see the edit. There was a mistake in my answer yesterday that was corrected today. Also there's another method that seems to be much faster than the other options.

Comment: @vaeVictis I did a test and it turns out, your version is virtually the same as my version for large arrays and better for small arrays. However, it turns out there's another option that's much faster than all of them.

Comment: @enke very nice test! I didn't know perfplot, awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension with [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) + [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html):

```
l = [l.sum() for l in np.split(a2, np.flatnonzero(~a2)) if l.sum() > 0]
```

Output:

```
>>> l
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with itertools

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

a2= np.array([False, False, True, False, False, True, True, True, False, False])

foo = [ sum( 1 for _ in group ) for key, group in itertools.groupby( a2 ) if key ]

print(foo)
```

output

```
[1, 3]
```

**Edit**:

Since you asked for performance too, I wrote this test code to check the performances of the three codes proposed so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import itertools
import numpy as np
import timeit

a2 = np.random.choice([True, False], 1000000)


start_time = timeit.default_timer()
out = [ar.sum() for ar in np.split(a2, np.where(np.diff(a2.astype(int))==1)[0]+1)[1:]]
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
foo = [ sum( 1 for _ in group ) for key, group in itertools.groupby( a2 ) if key ]
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
l = [l.sum() for l in np.split(a2, np.flatnonzero(~a2)) if l.sum() > 0]
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

print(out == foo == l)
```

Outputs are always like:

```
$ python3 test.py 
1.702160262999314
2.1189031369995064
4.760941952999929
True
```

So, the best solution is the one proposed by [enke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17521785/enke) , followed by mine and then the one proposed by [richardec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17242583/richardec)

Comment: Perhaps `len(list(group))` is more readable than `sum( 1 for _ in group )`?

Comment: @richardec perhaps... we will never know :)

Comment: @richardec seriously speaking, I wrote a test for performances (see the edit in my answer). It seems to me that `len(list(group))` slows down the procedure. Do you want to test too?

Comment: actually, I intended to test it myself but I forgot about it. Nice test :) So, haha, mine's the slowest? :D